# python - lxml: enforcing a specific order for attributes

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML writing script that outputs XML for a specific 3rd party tool.

I've used the original XML as a template to make sure that I'm building all the correct elements, but the final XML does not appear like the original.

I write the attributes in the same order, but lxml is writing them in its own order.

I'm not sure, but I suspect that the 3rd part tool expects attributes to appear in a specific order, and I'd like to resolve this issue so I can see if its the attrib order that making it fail, or something else.

Source element:

```
<FileFormat ID="1" Name="Development Signature" PUID="dev/1" Version="1.0" MIMEType="text/x-test-signature">
```

My source script:

```
sig.fileformat = etree.SubElement(sig.fileformats, "FileFormat", ID = str(db.ID), Name = db.name, PUID="fileSig/{}".format(str(db.ID)), Version = "", MIMEType = "")
```

My resultant XML:

```
<FileFormat MIMEType="" PUID="fileSig/19" Version="" Name="Printer Info File" ID="19">
```

Is there a way of constraining the order they are written?

Comment: Attribute order is meaningless in XML. It would be worth checking whether this tool is really that lame. You could use a templating system such as cheetah where you have control over attribute order. lxml has XSLT which has the advantage that you can just pass your existing lxml doc to it.

Comment: Attribute order has no significance in the validity of a XML document. So your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: I appreciate its meaningless in XML, the question is if its meaningful for the tool (and therefore if its manageable in lxml). Regardless, I can just spoof something based on the source.

Comment: If you don't mention the tool we have no hope in finding the problem with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Attribute ordering and readability**
As the commenters have mentioned, attribute order has no semantic significance in XML, which is to say it doesn't change the meaning of an element:

```
<tag attr1="val1" attr2="val2"/>

<!-- means the same thing as: -->

<tag attr2="val2" attr1="val1"/>
```

There is an analogous characteristic in SQL, where column order doesn't change
the meaning of a table definition. XML attributes and SQL columns are a *set*
(not an *ordered set*), and so all that can "officially" be said about either
one of those is whether the attribute or column is present in the set.

That said, it definitely makes a difference to human readability which order
these things appear in and in situations where constructs like this are authored and appear in text (e.g. source code) and must be interpreted, a careful ordering makes a lot of sense to me.

**Typical parser behavior**

Any XML parser that treated attribute order as significant would be out of compliance with the XML standard. That doesn't mean it can't happen, but in my experience it is certainly unusual. Still, depending on the provenence of the tool you mention, it's a possibility that may be worth testing.

As far as I know, `lxml` has no mechanism for specifying the order attributes appear in serialized XML, and I would be surprised if it did.

In order to test the behavior I'd be strongly inclined to just write a text-based template to generate enough XML to test it out:

```
id = 1
name = 'Development Signature'
puid = 'dev/1'
version = '1.0'
mimetype = 'text/x-test-signature'

template = ('<FileFormat ID="%d" Name="%s" PUID="%s" Version="%s" '
            'MIMEType="%s">')

xml = template % (id, name, puid, version, mimetype)
```

Comment: I went ahead and found out that the problem was simply it fell over with an uppercase .xml file extension... I played around with the attrib order, and can confirm that it has no impact on tool.

Comment: "attribute order has no semantic significance in XML" - well, that may be true but if you want to implement a custom canonicalization method (c14n) e.g. to sign an element, then the order of attributes does matter. Interestingly, php DOM uses so called "attribute nodes" and it is possible to insert before/after specific attributes. In lxml, that is impossible. :-(

Comment: "attribute order has no semantic significance in XML" Note however that XML is not only for computers, humans (unfortunately) have to read it as well... And when you have a config file, it very well might be the case that the order is important. Preserving order when writing in those cases is a desired feature.

Answer (score 19):

It looks like lxml serializes attributes in the order you set them:

```
>>> from lxml import etree as ET
>>> x = ET.Element("x")
>>> x.set('a', '1')
>>> x.set('b', '2')
>>> ET.tostring(x)
'<x a="1" b="2"/>'
>>> y= ET.Element("y")
>>> y.set('b', '2')
>>> y.set('a', '1')
>>> ET.tostring(y)
'<y b="2" a="1"/>'
```

Note that when you pass attributes using the ET.SubElement() constructor, Python constructs a dictionary of keyword arguments and passes that dictionary to lxml.  This loses any ordering you had in the source file, since Python's dictionaries are unordered (or, rather, their order is determined by string hash values, which may differ from platform to platform or, in fact, from execution to execution).

Comment: An interesting experiment would be to try passing an `OrderedDict` of attributes to `SubElement`.

Comment: I believe I once tried passing an OrderedDict to a function via ``f(**od)``, but, unfortunately, Python converts that OrderedDict into a regular dict and loses all order information.

Comment: @Marcin: This does in fact work, see my answer from a few months ago (I finally have enough reputation to comment here now). @Marius: The `SubElement` constructor implementation does not unpack a passed `attrib` dictionary (but yes, there is an optional `**extra` parameter which allows to specify attributes "one by one" and this does **not** preserve specification order).

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Note the lxml docs recommend using 'element.set(name, value)' instead of 'attrib[name] = value' and that also keeps order and neither seemed to change my performance tests (in the context of my project on a 500k file) versus **kwargs use. Ref: http://lxml.de/api/index.html "attrib: Element attribute dictionary. Where possible, use get(), set(), keys(), values() and items() to access element attributes."

Answer (score 16):

## OrderedDict of attributes

As of lxml 3.3.3 (perhaps also in earlier versions) you can pass an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) of attributes to the `lxml.etree.(Sub)Element` constructor and the order will be preserved when using `lxml.etree.tostring(root)`:

```
sig.fileformat = etree.SubElement(sig.fileformats, "FileFormat", OrderedDict([("ID",str(db.ID)), ("Name",db.name), ("PUID","fileSig/{}".format(str(db.ID))), ("Version",""), ("MIMEType","")]))
```

Note that the ElementTree API (`xml.etree.ElementTree`) does **not** preserve attribute order even if you provide an `OrderedDict` to the `xml.etree.ElementTree.(Sub)Element` constructor!

UPDATE: Also note that using the `**extra` parameter of the `lxml.etree.(Sub)Element` constructor for specifying attributes does **not** preserve attribute order:

```
>>> from lxml.etree import Element, tostring
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> root = Element("root", OrderedDict([("b","1"),("a","2")])) # attrib parameter
>>> tostring(root)
b'<root b="1" a="2"/>' # preserved
>>> root = Element("root", b="1", a="2") # **extra parameter
>>> tostring(root)
b'<root a="2" b="1"/>' # not preserved
```

Comment: Seems it's not work for `SubElement`, only for `Element`.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen order matter where the consumer of the XML is expecting canonicalized XML.  Canonical XML specifies that the attributes be sorted:

> in increasing lexicographic order with namespace URI as the primary
> key and local name as the secondary key (an empty namespace URI is
> lexicographically least). (section 2.6 of https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/)

So if your application is expecting the kind of order you would get out of canonical XML, lxml does support output in canonical form using the `method=` argument to print. (see heading C14N of https://lxml.de/api.html)

For example:

```
from lxml import etree as ET 
element = ET.Element('Test', B='beta', Z='omega', A='alpha') 
val = ET.tostring(element, method="c14n") 
print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

lxml uses libxml2 under the hood. It preserves attribute order, which means for an individual element you can sort them like this:

```py
x = etree.XML('<x a="1" b="2" d="4" c="3"><y></y></x>')
sorted_attrs = sorted(x.attrib.items())
x.attrib.clear()
x.attrib.update(sorted_attrs)
```

Not very helpful if you want them *all* sorted though. If you want them all sorted you can use the `c14n2` output method (XML Canonicalisation Version 2):

```py
>>> x = etree.XML('<x a="1" b="2" d="4" c="3"><y></y></x>')
>>> etree.tostring(x, method="c14n2")
b'<x a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4"><y></y></x>'
```

That will sort the attributes. Unfortunately it has the downside of ignoring `pretty_print`, which isn't great if you want human-readable XML.

If you use `c14n2` then lxml will use custom Python serialisation code to write the XML which calls `sorted(x.attrib.items()` itself for all attributes. If you don't, then it will instead call into libxml2's [`xmlNodeDumpOutput()`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDumpOutput) function which doesn't support sorting attributes but does support pretty-printing.

Therefore the only solution is to manually walk the XML tree and sort all the attributes, like this:

```py
from lxml import etree

x = etree.XML('<x a="1" b="2" d="4" c="3"><y z="1" a="2"><!--comment--></y></x>')
for el in x.iter(etree.Element):
    sorted_attrs = sorted(el.attrib.items())
    el.attrib.clear()
    el.attrib.update(sorted_attrs)

etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True)

# b'<x a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">\n  <y a="2" z="1">\n    <!--comment-->\n  </y>\n</x>\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate a new string, which gives order when compared, and gives value when print and get strings.

Here is an example:

```py
class S:
    def __init__(self, _idx, _obj):
        self._obj = (_idx, _obj)

    def get_idx(self):
        return self._obj[0]

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._obj[0] <= other.get_idx()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._obj[0] < other.get_idx()

    def __str__(self):
        return self._obj[1].__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._obj[1].__repr__()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self._obj[1] == other
        elif isinstance(other, S):
            return self._obj[
                       0] == other.get_idx() and self.__str__() == other.__str__()
        else:
            return self._obj[
                0] == other.get_idx() and self._obj[1] == other

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._obj[1] + other

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._obj[1].__hash__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._obj[1].__getitem__(item)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + self._obj[1]

list_sortable = ['c', 'b', 'a']
list_not_sortable = [S(0, 'c'), S(0, 'b'), S(0, 'a')]
print("list_sortable ---- Before sort ----")
for ele in list_sortable:
    print(ele)
print("list_not_sortable ---- Before sort ----")
for ele in list_not_sortable:
    print(ele)
list_sortable.sort()
list_not_sortable.sort()
print("list_sortable ---- After sort ----")
for ele in list_sortable:
    print(ele)
print("list_not_sortable ---- After sort ----")
for ele in list_not_sortable:
    print(ele)
```

running result:

```sh
list_sortable ---- Before sort ----
c
b
a
list_not_sortable ---- Before sort ----
c
b
a
list_sortable ---- After sort ----
a
b
c
list_not_sortable ---- After sort ----
c
b
a
dict_sortable ---- After sort ----
a 3
b 2
c 1
dict_not_sortable ---- After sort ----
c 1
b 2
a 3
```