# Rearrange the attributes in a node lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have an element node like

```
<Relationship Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Id="rId61" Target="media/image1.png"/>
```

I need the attributes to be sorted in an order. The output should look like

```
<Relationship Id="rId61" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="media/image1.png"/>
```

How do i rearrange this? Currently I am using lxml library

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a specific order of element attributes using `lxml`. `element.attrib` is a dictionary, dictionaries in python are unordered collections.

Also see:

- [python - lxml: enforcing a specific order for attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917943/python-lxml-enforcing-an-specific-order-for-attributes)