# Fix the location of attributes in etree.Element

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, xml.etree

I use the python, lxml package.  I am wondering if someone knows how to output an element with fixed specified locations for the attributes.

```
MMain = etree.Element('DockingConfig', FormatVersion="8", InsideFill="True", InnerMinimum="20, 20", SavedAt="1/27/2014 2:01:47 PM")
outfile.write(etree.tostring(MMain, pretty_print=True))
```

if I output this, it will sort out the attributes alphabetically, which is not what i want as an output.

My second question is that, how can I generate my output file with encoding of "Encode in UCS-2 Little edition". This makes it to be "utf-16"

```
print(etree.tostring(MMain, pretty_print=True, encoding="utf-16"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917943/python-lxml-enforcing-an-specific-order-for-attributes) seems to be a good answer.

As for your second question, the "tostring()" method follows [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-EncodingDecl) standard (as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)).

Comment: Sorry for my late replay, I did not have enough point to do an action. The first answer works well (thanks). I tried all different solutions for the second question. But still I am not able to make the file in Unicode format. The way I resolved the issue was using the "Type" command in windows added to my Python program to convert ANSI file format to Unicode.