# don't sort attrib for xml tree in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I have code:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("check", attrib={"p": "1","c": "2", "d": "3","v": "4"})
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
```

and I get:

```
<check c="2" d="3" p="1" v="4"/>
```

But i need without attribute sorting:

```
<check p="1" c="2" d="3" v="4"/>
```

How i can get it?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use OrderedDict to preserve attribute order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22596064/407651.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot control sort of attribute. but you can have access to attribute:

```
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
att = tree.attrib
print (att) # {attr_name : attr_value}
```

from "attr" you can get only attr_name:

```
attr_name = att.kyes() # ['attr_name_1', 'attr_name_2'...]
```